# Can I tell TypeScript that a Generic type has a constructor?

Tags: generics, typescript

I think I can do something like this to create a new instance of a Generic in TypeScript:

```
class Tree<T extends SomeInterface> {

    constructor(private elementType: {new(): T}) {
    }

    public Grow() {
        var newElement: T = new this.elementType();
        // ...
    }
}
```

But is there any way to let TypeScript know that a Generic has a `new()`?  In other words, is there any way to get something like this to work?

```
class Tree<T extends SomeInterface> { // <-- Modify the constraint?
    public Grow() {
        var newElement: T = new T();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the construct signature type in the constraint. But is `T` intended to be the type of the constructor function, or the type of the result of `new`ing some value? You're using it both ways in the posted examples

Comment: I've faworited this. Hope you will find the solution. As I've got from documentation (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics-generic-constraints) you cann't use type parameter in constraint like this: "function find<T, U extends Findable<T>>(n: T, s: U) { ...". So it seems to me like answer "No" on your question for a while.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh T is intended to be the type of the result... I guess I realize now from your question that `new` is called on a constructor - not on a "type".  So I guess to get my intended result, I'd have to create some kind of `Createable` interface, and give it a `Create()` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But is there any way to let TypeScript know that a Generic has a new()? In other words, is there any way to get something like this to work?

*Not Exactly*. Reason is that you *still need to pass in the entity that will New up the object for you*. You can't just use the compile time constraint`<T>` as a runtime `new T`.

```
interface SomeInterface{    
}

interface SomeInterfaceConstructor<T extends SomeInterface>{
    new (): T;
}


class Tree<T extends SomeInterface> {
    constructor(private elementType: SomeInterfaceConstructor<T>) {
    }
    public Grow() {
        var newElement = new this.elementType();
        // ...
    }
}
```